# Synchronising android app with google plus

Tags: android, google-plus

I am new to android programming.I want my app to interact with google plus but i have no idea about how it is done.The requirement is when someone updates any content of google plus account, the same update must be seen in the android app too.Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interacting with google+ can be possible,you can refer" Google+ Sign-in for Android " site(https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) .Google+ Sign-in also lets you grow your app engagement by letting your signed-in users create interactive posts to invite their friends to use your app. By connecting your users with Google, you will soon be able to influence your appearance in Google Play through trusted social recommendations that show your users their friends who are already using your app.This site gives you the full idea that how your app interact with google+ .